# MQ Websphere (C#) throws exception when initializing MQQueueManager

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I'm attempting to run a C# application I inherited which is supposed to connect to a Websphere MQ channel and write/read messages. I have IBM Websphere MQ 5.3 installed.

The exception occurs when the code instantiates a MQQueueManager object.

```
MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager("somename");
```

The exception thrown is
"A first chance exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' occurred in amqmdxcs.dll

Additional information: Unable to find an entry point named 'xtr_getTraceStatus' in DLL 'amqxcs2.dll'."

I'm totally new at Websphere MQ and do not even have a proper basic understanding, but I really need to get this application to run properly as soon as I can. Any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an old and unsupported version of MQ. Suggest you to upgrade to latest supported version of WebSphere MQ. Are you at the latest fix pack of MQ v5.3? It appears that there is some issue with the MQ you have installed.

Can you upgrade to MQ v71? You can just upgrade only the client and compile your .NET application. You can download the MQC71 client from [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24031412).

Comment: Thanks Shashi! You were right, after upgrading this error is solved. Thanks for your help